# How do I prevent validation when clicking a button in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have 1 form and 2 buttons, one within a form, one out side of a form on a page:

```
<form method="post">
    <button asp-page-handler="AddRecord" id="addRecordBtn" class="btn btn-sm 
    btn-secondary" type="submit">Add Record</button>
</form>
```

```
<button asp-page-handler="EmailData" id="emailData" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary data-btn">Email Data</button>
```

I've also created some custom validation. When I click the EmailData button, the custom validation fires and returns null as there's no form data. Both are POST.

How do I prevent this from happening? I can't seem to find an up to date answer for .NET Core.

Thanks

Comment: Well, for one, you can probably just make this a GET request instead, since you're not actually sending any data and its idempotent (presumably just sending an email and not actually making any changes server-side). You don't *need* a button element; you can use an anchor and style it as a button via the Boostrap classes you've already applied.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onsubmit`:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <button asp-page-handler="AddRecord" id="addRecordBtn" class="btn btn-sm 
    btn-secondary" type="submit">Add Record</button>
</form>
```

`return false` will prevent form `action`